# How do CO2 Fire extinguishers procure their CO2

Tags: everyday-chemistry

How do CO2 Fire extinguisher manufacturers get such a large amount of Carbon Dioxide? Do they get it through a chemical reaction or burning hydrocarbons?

Answer (score 1):

They just buy it from companies producing CO2. 
Actual sources may be sequestration from combustion (e.g. power plants) or fermentation (e.g. ethanol production) processes.